# (Theoretical Questions) Determine the following statements are true or false.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

It is true or false answer so lets get started.

1. False
2. True
3. False, In any ring R, a maximal ideal is an ideal M that is maximal in the set of all proper ideals of R, i.e. M is contained in exactly two ideals of R, namely M itself and the entire ring R. Every maximal ideal is in fact prime. In a principal ideal domain every nonzero prime ideal is maximal, but this is not true in general.
4. False, An ideal I in the ring R (with unity) is prime if and only if the factor ring R/I is an integral domain. In particular, a commutative ring is an integral domain if and only if {0} is a prime ideal.
5. True
6. False

I was wondering if somebody can check my proof and see if I made any mistakes or if they're correct. I want to thank you ahead of time for taking your time to do so.

Comment: Even if the instructions don't require a proof, it would be helpful if you provided a brief justification for your answers. There's no use in being right for wrong reasons, after all.

Comment: 4 is false, 5 is true

Comment: can we not merge 1 and 2: for any integer $\ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

You did not give any proofs or counterexamples. Giving these is more instructive.

1. False
2. True
3. True, read the question more carefully.
4. False. You give definitions but not an explanation why this is false. Try to come up with a couterexample. What integral domains do you know that are not a PID?
5. True
6. False

Comment: 5. is false. A variant of the primitive element theorem states that a finite field extension is simple iff it has finitely many intermediate fields. $\Bbb F_p(X^p,Y^p)/\Bbb F_p(X,Y)$ is a standard example of a field extension with finite degree which is not simple, hence it has infinitely many intermediate fields.